# Spinner режет строки

Tags: java, android-studio, android-spinner

Всем привет. Такая проблема. Spinner срезает строку. Точнее строка полностью не влезает в открытый spinner.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3">
    </Spinner>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.7" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Spinner spinner;
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.list, R.layout.spinner_close);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_open);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter)
        }
    }
```

spinner_open.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_open"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

spinner_close.xml

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_close"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сталкивался кто-нибудь с такой проблемой?

Comment: Скрин бы добавить

Comment: Скриншот добавил.

Comment: Выложите код самого <Spinner   ...   /> и визульное представление на экране до нажатия на него, и желательно полный код XML файла, представляющего Spinner